# Could you advise me on budget folding bikes

Tags: folding-bicycle, storage, transportation

I figured the best way for me to commute to work (3 - 4km) during the summer may be riding a bike. The problem is that I live on the fifth floor and there's no elevator in my building, thus I need something fairly light and easily transportable. I'm short and lightweight myself, so 16kg bike is a bit too heavy but something around 12kg may do.

Could you recommend something specific? I'm thinking of something like this: https://silverbacklab.com/product/soto/

I'm afraid I may be overlooking something. Anyways, despite the commuting aspect It has been awhile and I really miss riding a bike.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Product recommendations are deliberately off topic on this site. See [What Topics Can I Ask About Here](vhttps://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for why that is.

Comment: I'm sorry. I saw people discussing different brands.

Comment: Unless your stairwell is particularly tight, you don't need to limit yourself to folding bikes, I carried my standard bike up 3 flights of stairs for several years without difficulty, I just slung it over my shoulder. There are even [bike bags](https://www.trekbikes.com/ca/en_CA/equipment/cycling-components/bike-bags-baskets-panniers/bike-bags-panniers/bontrager-shoulder-holder-frame-bag/p/08101/) designed to pad the bike for easy carrying by shoulder.

Comment: My road bike (10kg) is lighter than either my Brompton or Dahon folding bikes.

Comment: Bike weights are somewhat dependent on your height too. Also, once you move out of [tag:BSO]'s, finding bikes suitable for commuting that are ~12 kg are pretty easy; a "heavy" surly cross check in 58 cm is probably around 12-13 kg stock, and its not hard to find something lighter and cheaper for commuting.

Comment: Does your building offer a bike room?  It may be a carpark or something on the basement level.  Talk to your building management.  Sometimes they disallow bikes in stairwells because of blocking-risks, so ground floor storage is the solution.  Do other people in your building move bikes about ?

Comment: This question will likely get closed for being too "product recommendation"  When you get a bit more rep, consider joining the [chat] for less structured discussion :)